# Weak convergence for probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\mu_n$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, and suppose that $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu_n$ converges for any $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$(Note that we don't know what it converges to).

Prove that there is a probability measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ weakly, that is, $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu_n$ converges to $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu$ for any $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$.

By Rieze representation, it is easy to see that there is a measure $\mu$ with $\mu(\mathbb{R})\leq 1$ such that $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu_n$ converges to $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu$ for any $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$(continuous with compact support).

My question is how to show that $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$, or how to prove $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu_n$ converges to $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu$ for any $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$(bounded continuous function).

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but you need to share your own thoughts before people will help you on this site. As it stands, we have a "Problem Statement Question", which is likely to be downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i have edited the question more carefully.

Comment: $1=\int 1 d\mu_n \to \int 1 d\mu=\mu (\mathbb R)$.

Comment: This is still confusing. If you have already proved that there exists $\mu$ such that $\int fd\mu_n\to \int fd\mu$ for all $f\in C_b(\mathbb R)$, then $\mu(\mathbb R)=1$ can be seen easily by just putting $f=1$.

Comment: We can just prove $\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_n$ converges to  $\int f\mathrm{d}\mu$  for  continuous function with compact support set.

Comment: And the problem is $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu_n$ conveeges, but we don't know what it converges to.

Comment: So how to prove that $\mu$ is a probability measure?

Comment: @yxyt I think now I understand your question which really should be more properly written.  What you are claiming is equivalence of vague convergence with weak convergence which simply isn't true. For $\mu$ to be a Probability measure , the sequence $\mu_{n}$ needs to be [tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures) . Otherwise the conclusion fails.

Comment: @yxyt The jump from compactly supported to bounded functions is what apriori requires $\mu$ to be a Probability measure which is guaranteed by tightness of the sequence and is also a necessary condition.

Comment: The proof for $\int f\,d\mu_{n}$ converges for all $f$ implies tightness of the sequence is not as easy as I initially thought. Or I might be having a brain freeze and not seeing something easy. If we manage to show that the sequence is tight, then there will exist a subsequence $\mu_{n_{k}}$ weakly converging to a probability measure $\mu$. Then the whole sequence $\int f\,d\mu_{n}\to\int f\,d\mu$ due to uniqueness of limits. So all it essentially needs to be done is showing that the sequence $\mu_{n}$ is tight.

Comment: I'll take the liberty to ask it myself as a separate question and then inform you once I get an answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. By the way, the problem is exercise 4.4.11  in ''A Course in Probability Theory'' by Kai Lai Chung. And here is a hint, i don't konw if it works.

Comment: @yxyt If you see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702942/a-sufficient-condition-for-tightness-of-probability-measures) , there is a referene to Bogachev's book , Weak Convergence of Measures , where tightness of the sequence follows from a corollary to Prokhorov's theorem. I will try to fashion a direct proof in the next few days when I find time. In the meantime, keep an eye on my question as well as someone might be able to provide a direct proof. Note that below the upvote/downvote option , there's an option to follow and save a question. I suggest you do so.

Comment: I get it, thanks.

Comment: Theorem 7.5.2 in [this book](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~sergei.kuksin/MyBooks/bookArmen.pdf) is more general: this is the same claim for random measures. Maybe you can simplify the proof.

Comment: Thanks for you reference. It would be nice to have a more direct proof, since it's an exercise in Kai Lai Chuang 's book.