# A sufficient condition for tightness of probability measures

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence, weak-topology

For a sequence $\mu_{n}$ of Borel Probability measures, does $\int f\,d\mu_{n}$ converging for all $f\in C_{b}(\Bbb{R})$ imply that $\mu_{n}$ is a tight sequence?

This is pertaining to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702266/weak-convergence-for-probability-measure). Users(with sufficient privileges) can  view my deleted answer where I made the horribly stupid mistake of approximating $\mathbf{1}_{[-M,M]}$ under the supremum norm  by continuous bounded functions .

The condition reeks of an application of Uniform Boundedness Principle , but it only yields a bound with the $L^{\infty}$ norm of the form $\sup_{n}|\int f\,d\mu_{n}|\leq C||f||_{L^{\infty}}$ which is not very helpful as we would like to approximate $\mathbf{1}_{[-M,M]}$ by a sequence say $g_{k}$ of continuous bounded functions . So ideally, a bound with the $L^{1}$ norm is what would do the job. Then we can approximate as $k\to\infty$ (uniformly in $n$) $\mu_{n}[-M,M]$ with $\int g_{k}\,d\mu_{n}$ and then use Cauchyness of the sequence $\int g_{k}\,d\mu_{n}$ to prove that $\mu([-M,M])$ is tight.

However, I find no easy way of countering this . I might be having a brain freeze so please excuse my stupidity if I am missing something very easy.

Comment: (+1) Don't be too hard on yourself!

Comment: That is (part of) Corollary 2.3.5 in Bogachev's "Weak Convergence of Measures." The proof there is actually a modification of a part of the proof of Prohorov's theorem; it is somewhat messy.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks for the excellent reference(I usually search only in Billingsley for such results) . I agree that it's somewhat messy. I'll try to simplify the proof if I can. Let's see . You might as well post your comment as an answer. I'll wait one or two days to see if others can provide an alternative approach though.

Comment: I secretly hope that someone can give a more direct proof.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I've been struggled with a similar problem (which was in an assignment).

・Assuming the contrary, $\exists\epsilon>0$ s.t. $\forall K\subset\mathbb{R}$:compact, $\exists n\in\mathbb{N},\mu_n(K)<1-\epsilon$. In this situation, Show that $\{n\in\mathbb{N};\mu_n(K)<1-\epsilon\}$ is an infinite set.

・Construct $\{\mu_{n_{\ell}}\}$;a subsequence of $\{\mu_n\}$, and $\{K_{\ell}\}$;a sequence of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, s.t.
$$
\mu_{n_{\ell}}(K_{\ell})\geq\epsilon \\
|x-y|\geq 1(\forall x\in K_{\ell}, y\in K_m(\ell\neq m))
$$
(Hint:For example, $n_1=1$ and $K_1$ can be taken as $\mu_1(K_1)\geq\epsilon$.
$n_2$ can be taken as $\mu_{n_2}(K_1(1))<1-\epsilon$, where $K(1)=\{x\in\mathbb{R};\displaystyle\min_{y\in K}\{|x-y|\}<1\}$. How to choose $K_2\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus K_1(1)$? $n_{\ell}$ and $K_{\ell}$ can be taken inductively.)

・Apploximate the characteristic function of $K_{\ell}$ by continuous bounded functions. (I write that as $f_{\ell}$.) It is expected that
$$\int f_{\ell}d\mu_{n_{\ell}}\geq\mu_{n_{\ell}}(K_{\ell})\geq\epsilon.$$
Obviously if there exists $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f d\mu_n$, for any $\{n_m\}$(:subsequence of $\mathbb{N}$, $n_m\to\infty(m\to\infty)$), $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f d\mu_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\int f d\mu_{n_m}$. Derive a contrudiction using $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int 1 d\mu_n=1$,
and
$\forall N,\exists g_1,\ldots,g_N\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $g_1+\ldots+g_N\leq 1,\displaystyle\int g_i d\mu_{n^i_{m}}\geq\epsilon(\forall m)$.

Sorry for my terrible English. Also, this is my first answer at stackexchange, so my post might be against the rules of this website. For more, please show [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61943-4)
(pp.362-366, I reffered to this for my assignment).